# ¿Como imprimir una variable al lado de un texto en Python?

Tags: python

Estoy mirando cosas en python y como imprimo en pantalla una variable acompañado de un texto, así: `print(x,"Es primo")`

Comment: Pero... aunque la pregunta ya está resuelta, no la entiendo ¿no te estás respondiendo tú mismo con lo de `print(x, "es primo")`?

Comment: @abulafia la verdad es que puse la lenguaje mal, esto era para Lenguaje R, pero ya me ayuda para dudas en Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Casting a str:**

```
n = 2
w = "nueva"
print(w + " linea " + str(n))
```

- Transformar un elemento a tipo str y concatenar como un todo

**Método format de las cadenas:**

```
n = 2
w = "nueva"
print("{} linea {}".format(w,n))
```

- Usamos format para que cada elemento se coloque en su correspondiente posicion

**Print separando cada variable por comas y usando el parámetro sep:**

```
n = 2
w = "nueva"
print(w, "linea", n, sep=' ')
```

- Utilizamos sep, como separador lo que separara, en este caso un espacio.

**En Python >= 3.6 puedes usar los literales de cadena formateados:**

```
n = 2
w = "nueva"
print(f"{w} linea {n}")
```

- Permitirá colocar dentro de las llaves una variable.